How to inlet parallel and perpendicularly?
I am trying to do a windshield for a car in 3D and I want to be able to apply a material on the inside of my face without coloring the exterior but when I use the inset tool, it is creating a face that is directly linked to my previous face but not the way I want.

In my drawing I want to be able to not apply a material to the square and the upper line while applying a material on the vertical line + main shape because I am using a mirrored shape.


Here is a picture of my car to better illustrate : https://imgur.com/a/wxCbE7C

 I  hotkey for inset. If you don't like the resulting topology, you should edit it. You can merge vertices( M ), edges or faces, you can move vertices( G ), slide them( Shift  +  V ), connect on surface( J ), dissolve( Ctrl  +  X ) and use other modelling tools to create whatever topology you like. See Mesh, Vertex, Edge, Face menus in 3d viewport header when in edit mode. I know there is a lot, but that's all the functions you need to learn to manipulate topology.
See the info in the header of 3d viewport when in some operation as well as Adjust Last Operation panel after you complete the operation. For example, when you hit  I  for inset operator, it has additional options:



I found the solution on my own I just had to use the Knife Tool and press <Enter/kbd>.
